# How to capture picture with AVCaptureSession in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avcapturesession

I have a `UIViewController` in which I use `AVCaptureSession` to show the camera and it is working just fine and fast. I placed a `UIButton` object on top of this camera view and added a `IBAction` for the button.

This is how it looks like right now:

[image: my camera app]

Now I want to get the picture of the current camera view when the user taps the button:

```
@IBAction func takePicture(sender: AnyObject) {
    // omg, what do do?!
}
```

I have no idea whatsoever on how I can do that. I imagined there could have been something like:

```
let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var myDearPicture = captureSession.takePicture() as UIImage // something like it?
```

The full link for the controller code is here https://gist.github.com/rodrigoalvesvieira/392d683435ee29305059, hope it helps

Comment: Copy existing libraries [DFCamera](https://github.com/danielebogo/DBCamera), [TGCameraViewController](https://github.com/tdginternet/TGCameraViewController)

Comment: SUPERB  camera sample code ... http://drivecurrent.com/devops/using-swift-and-avfoundation-to-create-a-custom-camera-view-for-an-ios-app/#comment-4686

Answer (score 107, accepted):

AVCaptureSession Sample

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    let stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
    var error: NSError?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices().filter{ $0.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) && $0.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back }
        if let captureDevice = devices.first as? AVCaptureDevice  {

            captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice, error: &error))
            captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
            captureSession.startRunning()
            stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG]
            if captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
                captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
            }
            if let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession) {
                previewLayer.bounds = view.bounds
                previewLayer.position = CGPointMake(view.bounds.midX, view.bounds.midY)
                previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                let cameraPreview = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height))
                cameraPreview.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
                cameraPreview.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:"saveToCamera:"))
                view.addSubview(cameraPreview)
            }
        }
    }
    func saveToCamera(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
            stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection) {
                (imageDataSampleBuffer, error) -> Void in
                let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer)
                 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage(data: imageData), nil, nil, nil)
            }
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

UIImagePickerController Sample

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewer: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
            dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
             imageViewer.image = image
    }
    @IBAction func presentImagePicker(sender: AnyObject) {

        if UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable( UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.Front) {

            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
            presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the question is about AVCaptureSession? why imagePicker?

Comment: @JunchaoGu I have added a AVCaptureSession sample also

Comment: I finished capturing with AVSession yesterday already but thanks anyway for your answer @Leo Dabus

Comment: Is there a way to get the preview layer to update when the device is changed to a horizontal position?

Comment: @LeoDabus Can you help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34574932/how-to-change-orientation-in-avcapturemoviefileoutput-in-swift

Comment: @MiteshDobareeya Apple has a very good camera Swift/Obj-c code sample available at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html if you can't access it you can download it from here https://www.dropbox.com/s/cn73s7zwtpzib7q/AVCAM.zip?dl=1

Answer (score 12):

As `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` is deprecated, I created another Swift example of using `AVCaptureSession` and `AVCapturePhotoOutput` in iOS 10. Check [this](https://github.com/linhcn/AVCamSample) out.

Comment: You might want to include the most relevant portions of your sample code.