# How to launch camera on viewDidLoad with UIImagePickerControllerDelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, camera

I have a new iOS app in Swift where I'm trying to show the camera as soon as the app is launched. In my view controller I have a single `UIView` object which I try to fill with the camera.

The code in my view controller calls `UIImagePickerController` in the `viewDidLoad` method but nothing happens.

Here is the code, any idea why nothing happens? Isn't the camera supposed to open on app launch with this code?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewer: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable(   UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.Front) {
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
            presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            println("no front camera available")
        }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        imageViewer.image = image
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: if I add a button to the storyboard, connect it to the code and put the code from `viewDidLoad` in it, the camera works when the button is clicked:

```
@IBAction func presentImagePicker(sender: AnyObject) {

    if UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable( UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.Front) {
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I know that the camera works, but how to make it work without having to press a button?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the solution for you.

Put your code in `viewDidAppear` method this way:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable( UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.Front) {
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

This will load camera when your app start.

Trying to do it in viewDidLoad won't work because that is called after the view is first created, and the view isn't a subview of anything else at that point.

Comment: @Leonardo Savio Dabus Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28756363/how-to-capture-picture-with-avcapturesession-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

 if UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable( UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.Front) {
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
}
```