# Wrong pin entry, snap a photo without presenting the camera on screen

Tags: ios, swift, camera

I am trying to have my application take a photo of an "intruder" when the wrong pin is entered into my application.

I have set up the UIImagePickerController(Below) and can make the application display the camera and take photos with no problem what so ever.

```
picker = UIImagePickerController() //make a clean controller
picker.delegate = self
picker.allowsEditing = false
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
picker.cameraCaptureMode = .Photo
presentViewController(picker,animated: true,completion: nil)
```

Then i proceed to attempt this as to make the new set up for the picker

```
picker.showsCameraControls = false
```

I know that has to be set to false to call `picker.takePicture()`

Now I dont want to present the picker viewController and be able to call `takePicture()` but this is not hitting the delegate method of didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo.

I have tried using a custom overlay as well, but to no avail of 100% hiding the camera.

How do I go about not showing or displaying the camera on screen and being able to grab this picture of the front camera?

I have permission for access as well.

The other question posted on here of a similar topic does not solve this issue for help in swift.

Is the only way possible using AVFoundation?
If so, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Where do you set the image picker's `delegate` property?

Comment: within the same function that set up is taking place

Comment: updated it so it is easier to see. The set up for picker happens. Then I want to be able to have an action or function call that will `takePicture()` but for now it has to present the viewController

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28756363/how-to-capture-picture-with-avcapturesession-in-swift You can just hide the preview layer.

Comment: Do you mean to not present the view controller? Or something else?

Comment: Using AVCaptureSession, not image picker.

Comment: Is this the only way to not show the camera and have the image be taken?

Comment: Can you show me what to exclude entirely? Is it just the preview layer? Any help on this would be great, I am not too familiar with AVFoundation